# function template specialization between string literal (const char[]) and const char*

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to have a variadic function `f(p1,p2,...)` that `memcpy()` each of its arguments to a destination one by one. To save run-time overhead, I would prefer variadic function template over `va_list,va_start,...`. Assume that arguments are either basic data types (int, double, etc) or C-string. As you may expect, C-string arguments need to be handled carefully. I need to `strlen()` to get the length of the C-string in order to copy correctly. Consider the following code.

```
void f() { }

// template #1
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void f(T t, Args... args) {
    cout << "in f(T t, Args... args)" << endl;
    f(args...);
}
 //template #2                                                                            
template<typename... Args>
void f(const char* t, Args... args) {
    cout << "in f(const char* t, Args... args)" << endl;
    f(args...);
}
```

It works well for

```
int x = 3; f(x); 
f("hello");
const char* p = "world"; f(p);
string s = "stack"; f(s.c_str());
```

But for calls like `f("hello")` I would like my `f()` be clever enough to say "Haha, I know "hello" is a string-literal, const char _some_name_[6]. I would not be that stupid to call `strlen(p)` to tell me the length." So I add the following template specialization.

```
// template #3
template<uint8_t N, typename... Args>
void f(const char (&s)[N], Args... args) {
    cout << "in f(const char (&s)[N], Args... args)" << endl;
    f(args...);
}
```

With these three templates (#1, #2 and #3), the compiler(clang++) complains ambiguity of`f("hello")` as

```
/*
t4.cpp:30:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f("hello");
    ^
t4.cpp:16:6: note: candidate function [with Args = <>]
void f(const char* t, Args... args) {
     ^
t4.cpp:22:6: note: candidate function [with N = '\x06', Args = <>]
void f(const char (&s)[N], Args... args) {
     ^
t4.cpp:10:6: note: candidate function [with T = const char *, Args = <>]
void f(T t, Args... args) {
     ^
*/
```

**Question:** How can I make `f()` smart enough to distinguish between string literals (or const char []) and char *?

Comment: This may not be a great idea. Consider `const char foo[100] = "bar"; f(foo);`.

Comment: It seems your compiler issue,gcc ok. f("Hello") output  "in f(const char (&s)[N], Args... args)"

Comment: @RonTang [My GCC says otherwise](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/378b33456c9604ba).

Comment: @T.C. My GCC 4.6 says ok.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?